# Multiple non-simultaneous Java client-server connections using always the same port

Tags: java, sockets, reusability, connection

I'm trying to test a scenario where one server accepts connections(one each time) from one client, using always the same ports (on the server and on the client side).

The purpose is to have 1 client application sending little pieces of data at a rate bigger than 100/min. The well obvious solution would be to have an always connected link between the client and the server, but this is production stuff, and that would require bigger changes in the code that is already implemented. With the solution we have implemented today, we always have +-1K of connections in `TIME_WAIT`, and I want to get rid of them.

I have implemented a simple tester, and the code is:

```java
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket ssock = null;
        try {
            ssock = new ServerSocket();
            ssock.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Common.SERVER_PORT));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while(true){
            try{
                Socket cSock = ssock.accept();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cSock.getInputStream()));
                reader.readLine();

                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(cSock.getOutputStream());
                writer.println(Common.SERVER_SEND);
                writer.flush();

                reader.close();
                writer.close();
                cSock.close();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InetSocketAddress cliAddr = new InetSocketAddress(
                InetAddress.getByName(args[0]), 
                Common.CLIENT_PORT);

        InetSocketAddress srvAddr = new InetSocketAddress(
                InetAddress.getByName(args[1]), 
                Common.SERVER_PORT);

        for(int j=1;j<=50;j++){
            Socket sock = null;
            try{
                sock = new Socket();
                sock.setReuseAddress(true);
                sock.bind(cliAddr);
                sock.connect(srvAddr);

                PrintWriter writer = 
                        new PrintWriter(
                                sock.getOutputStream());

                writer.println(Common.CLIENT_SEND);
                writer.flush();

                BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                        sock.getInputStream()));
                reader.readLine();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }finally{
                if(sock!=null) sock.close();
                System.out.println("Done " + j);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Common {
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 9009;
    public static final int CLIENT_PORT = 9010;
    public static final String CLIENT_SEND = "Message";
    public static final String SERVER_SEND = "OK";
}
```

When executing the client and server, on windows hosts, in one client execution I always get

```java
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

When executing the client and the server in linux hosts, on some client executions I get a

```java
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address
```

I've been killing my head over this behavior. Can someone please tell me if it is possible to do what I want, and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So you have a lot of connections and you want to speed it up with a big block of code, and it's not working, figure it out for me?  Or is your question rather about the fact that your client code can't seem to find the server?  If it's the latter, you should edit your question so that it's obvious.

Comment: I only want to improve the big block of code that is already implemented... the code above is just a test aplication!

Comment: The client does find, connects and exchange some messages with the server, but it doesn't work like a clock. My guess is this is happening because, the 2 applications can't control the shutdown of the connection in both ends, and everything gets mixed up.

Comment: Why are you always using the same client port? This is poor practice.

Comment: I don't believe this: `java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address`. I believe this is a `BindException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the TIME_WAIT state, don't be the peer that receives the close. Be the peer that *initiates* the close. In this case, close the connection immediately after reading the response, and have the server cycle around looking for another request so that it reads the EOF rather than just closing the connection immediately after sending the response. However this will only make the problem worse, as all the TIME_WAIT states will accumulate at the server rather than at the client. On the other hand, the server is now structured to accept multiple requests per connection, so then all you have to do is adapt the clients to use a connection pool and all your problems are solved.

Comment: Passing the TIME_WAIT connections to the server side is not an option. It seems to me that i will have to make bigger changes in the client and in the server...

Comment: I agree it's not an option, indeed I said so, but what about the rest of what I said? Why are you using a single client port? When are you going to answer the questions you've been asked here?